# Why does DataGridView adopt the font of a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When I set the Font of a Form the DataGridView adopts the same font.

Why does the DataGridView adopt the font of the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for [`DataGridView.Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.font.aspx):

> The `Font` property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a `Button` will have the same `BackColor` as its parent `Form` by default. For more information about ambient properties, see the `AmbientProperties` class or the `Control` class overview.

In other words, it sounds like it's behaving exactly as documented. If you want it to use a font *other* than the form's font, set the property explicitly.

Comment: I did set all DefaultCellStyle properties, but the font of the form is still used.

Comment: @Rookian: Given that this is the first time you've mentioned DefaultCellStyle, now would be a good time to update your post with a short but complete example, explaining why you think a different font should be used.

Comment: Now it works! I made a little mistake. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this same issue, where I have a default font on the form but I want the `DataGridView` to have a different font.

You can fix this by placing a Load event that will change the font.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{  
   // set to your font you want.
   this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 15);
}
```

Or place the `DataGridView` inside of a `GroupBox` and set the `GroupBox` to the font that I want -- this fix is ugly but it works.